# Macro for degree symbol

Tags: symbols

I wanted to find a simple way to made **degree symbol °** and have tried `textcomp` and `gensymb`, but none of them works. I wanted to avoid using `^{\circ}`, which isn't nice when you have a long document. I thought may be something easy can be achievable, e.g. `\degree`?

Comment: Have a look at [“How to look up a math symbol?”](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.

Comment: You could define your own `\degree` using `\newcommand{\degree}{$^{\circ}$}` or better (using packages `xspace` and `amsmath`) `\newcommand{\degree}{\ensuremath{{}^{\circ}}\xspace}`. However, lockstep's answer might still be preferable.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Anything wrong with `textcomp`'s `\textdegree`?

Comment: I updated yesterday (TexShop), and made sure my files were intact after that. In fact, even for the first time that I installed it didn't work.    @ Martin - Do add the `\newcomand{}...' in the main '.cls' file?

Comment: @BrettHarry: `textcomp` is not only a package but also provides fonts (I presume) which complicates the installation. I recommend to install it over the package manager of your TeX distribution.

Comment: @Martin: OK! Did you mean I install the package first then add the files to folders of the main package? I only get about 4 `.sty` files of `textcomp`. Sometimes I'm do wonder how to install different products but end up piling them in folders when they contain the same suffix .e.g all `.sty` files.

Comment: @BrettHarry: Sorry, I can't help you. I never need to install any fonts by myself.

Comment: @BrettHarry  You work on a mac, so do you install MacTex or BasicTeX? I recommend MacTeX if you begin with TeX. BasicTeX comes only with latin modern font.

Comment: @Martin @ lockstep @ Altermundus: Thanks! Your ideas worked....I corrected my installations of MacTex and used `\degree`. @ Tobi: great idea! Never thought that's possible.

Comment: I landed here because in `textcomp` manual (version 29-octobre-2014 here) there is no mention of `\textdegree`... ;-)

Answer (score 35):

Maybe it’s a good alternative to use `siunitx`

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
    Works in text \ang{45} an in math $\ang{2.4}$.
    Even with minutes and seconds: \ang{40;12;08}.
\end{document}
```

It also gives you the oportunity to set all numbers in the same style an change it globally if it’s requested, e. g. changing from period to comma: 1.234 --> 1,234

Edit: To type radians just use the `\radian` unit. One may likes to define an own macro.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcommand{\rad}[1]{\SI{#1}{\radian}}
\begin{document}
    \SI{\pi}{\radian}
    \rad{\pi/2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For the sake of completeness, is there a way to insert an angle in radians?

Comment: @Dror: How do you mark radians? As far as I know they are simple decimal numbers (`\num{3.14}`) or multiples of π (`$2\pi/3$`), aren’t they?

Comment: Well, you would like to add the "unit" at the end of the number, as you could just as well have the notion of `\pi degrees`. Any number can measure either radians or degrees. A more or less standard notation for radians would be something like `\mathrm{rad}` I guess.

Comment: @Dror: (Sorry for the late reply …) At my university we usually don’t mark radians we just write the number – normally the the context makes clear that an angle is meant. If you like to ad “rad” you may use siunitx’ `\radian` as shown in my edit.

Comment: +1, you could also add \SI{20}{\celsius} as an example if the OP is asking for temperature.

Comment: Hm … I think the questions asks about angles, but it’s good to have this advice in your comment :-)

Comment: :) True I also think the question is about angles.

Answer (score 6):

I prefer this solution

```
\renewcommand{\deg}{\ensuremath{^{\circ}}\xspace}
```

because it also works in math mode.
(At least for me, `\textdegree` does not work in math mode, i.e.

```
$> 30\textdegree$
```

does not work, but

```
$> 30\deg$
```

does.

Comment: Related : http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34830/when-not-to-use-ensuremath-for-math-macro

Answer (score 4):

Using answers from [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/84469/16923), I've had good results with the following code:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % interpret input as unicode
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % choose main font encoding (Cork)
\usepackage{textcomp}       % additional symbols using companion encoding TS1
\usepackage{gensymb}        % provides macro \degree which works in text and math
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B0}{\degree} % Allow entering ° instead of \degree
```

As your original question states that [`gensymb`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/gensymb) didn't work for you, I assume that either the [`fontenc`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontenc) or the [`textcomp`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/textcomp) lines were missing in your setup, or some part of your TeX installation was missing, as these packages are usually shipped with your TeX distribution. The `gensymb` package goes to great length to provide its symbols from various sources, so it will behave differently depending on which other packages are loaded. See [its documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/was/gensymb.pdf) for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can cover math and text in one command using `\ifmmode`:

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\degC}{}{%
   {\ifmmode\text{\textdegree C}%
    \else\textdegree C\fi}\xspace%
}
```

where `\textdegree` could be instead be `\symbol{"00B0}` if you favor unicode.

It may be worth mentioning that `\textdegree` and `$^\circ$` produce different glyphs. The first uses `\textdegree` (or `\symbol{"00B0}`) and the second `$^\circ$`.

[image: The first uses <code>\textdegree</code> (or <code>\symbol{"00B0}</code>) and the second <code>$^\circ$</code>]