# Unicode degree symbol ° in math formulas: \textdegree invalid in math mode

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, unicode, degrees

I'd like to be able to simply input a degree symbol as ° in my source code. German keyboards have a key for this, and it makes the source so much more readable. I'm using `pdflatex` from TeXLive 2012, and this minimal reproducing example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
Degree symbol in plain text works: 90° is a right angle.
Degree in math won't work: $\cos(90°) = 0$.
\end{document}
```

Compiling this document, I get the message

```
LaTeX Warning: Command \textdegree invalid in math mode on input line 11.
```

printed twice. Looking at the log for this run, I see an additional error message

```
Missing character: There is no <B0> in font cmr10!
```

where `<B0>` actually refers to a single byte that does not form a valid UTF-8 sequence, so is not properly printable on my console.

I have a rough idea where all of this comes from, but little idea on how to solve this. I'd like to either make the `\textdegree` symbol work in math mode as well, or have the engine substitute some different command in place of my unicode code point. Ideally, that command would choose the right form depending on whether or not the current mode is math mode, which I don't know how to check (yet). For the final result, it would be nice if the symbol looked the same in both text and math modes, so I'd probably aim for a solution that dies switch to text mode to output that symbol.

But perhaps there is an easier way to do all this. Perhaps there even is a package for this. Searching through previous posts here, I found there is a package `unicode-math`, but that does not work with pdfLaTeX, and switching the engine does not appear to be a reasonable requirement for most of my applications.

Comment: Use XeTeX/LuaTeX and `unicodemath`.

Comment: @Martin: apparently, in some distributions (f.i. `texlive-2014` on Gentoo) the correct name of the package is `unicode-math`!

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The code below should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\begin{document}
Degree symbol in plain text works: 90° is a right angle.
Degree in math now work: $\cos(90\degree) = 0$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want to use the ° character also in math mode, do `\usepackage{newunicodechar}` and
`\newunicodechar{°}{\degree}`

Comment: @egreg: Nice package, good to know. For obvious reasons I get a `Warning: Redefining Unicode character`. But this appears to be harmless enough, and the combination of `gensymb`and `newunicodechar` really looks like what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: For reference: As I found no easy way to undefine the character in order to avoid the warning, I decided to use `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B0}{\degree}` in at least one project. I don't want to get into a habit of ignoring warnings, and that particular prelude is often used but rarely edited, so actually looking up the codepoint once isn't that much work.

Comment: Plain text rendering doesn't work with `LuaTex`.

Comment: All that just to get the degree symbol? An easier way when using static formulas is to do 90^o.

Answer (score 32):

That is why you have the `siunitx` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
Degree symbol in plain text works: 90\si{\degree} (or \SI{90}{\degree}) is a right angle.
Degree in math would work: $\cos(90\si{\degree}) = 0$.
\end{document}
```

[image]

As noted by cgnieder, `\ang` can also be used for this purpose:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
Degree symbol in plain text works: \ang{90} is a right angle.
Degree in math would work: $\cos(\ang{90}) = 0$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or `\SI{90}{\degree}`.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear enough, but I'm specifically interested in solutions that allow me to enter ° without having to use any macro instead or in addition to that.

Comment: With `siunitx` I believe one should used `\ang{90}` here.

Comment: Sure, it doesn't fit the needs of the OP... However, it is semantically very clean. That's why I'd prefer it, anyway.

Comment: As a physicist I would say that this is (currently) the best of all answers! Nevertheless I think, it is defined via `\textdegree`.

Answer (score 15):

I use `^{\circ}` in math mode to get the degree symbol. It's worked every time.  I have run into compatibility issues with some other code/package combinations.

Comment: That's all well and good, but it's not really relevant to the question of how to use the nice easy to read inline degree sign.

Comment: relevant to the OP's question or not, it helped me get something that works as degree sign, so +1

Comment: This approach doesn't actually produce a degree symbol -- take a look at copy-paste text from your final PDF.

Comment: This circle is actually larger than a degree symbol, and this looks odd when compared to the text mode symbol.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't need `textcomp` package, removing it and changing `utf8` option of `inputenc` to `utf8x` might work for you as it did for me.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
Degree symbol in plain text works: 90° is a right angle.
Degree in math won't work: $\cos(90°) = 0$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I'd recommend `utf8x`; for instance it's incompatible with `biblatex`

Comment: @egreg well, that is a one large drawback but I am still putting this as an option should some people find it useful.

Comment: I still get the warning, but the symbol is there in the output. Nice. Biblatex doesn't bother me for now. It's good to know about that option (it isn't particularly prominent in the docs), to decide on a per-case basis.

Comment: It does emit a warning, not an error, but it does that even with the code exactly as you posted it.

Answer (score 5):

I ended up using the `gensymb` package from [Papiro's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84471/16923) to get the `\degree` command, combined with a line to bind that to the `°` symbol which was inspired by a comment to that answer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00B0}{\degree}
\begin{document}
Degree symbol in plain text still works: 90° is a right angle.
Degree in math now works as well: $\cos(90°) = 0$.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define new command `\degree`

```
\newcommand{\degree}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
```

Use it

```
right angle: $90\degree$
hot water: $99.8\degree C$
```

etc.

Comment: As noted in comments on some of the other answers, I think the OP is looking to use the Unicode symbol directly.

Comment: What should be the advantage to use `^\circ` in contrast to `siunitx`?