# texworks says } was inserted

Tags: align

I keep getting this error, but I can`t seem to find the the problem in the text.

```
[1{C:/ProgramData/MiKTeX/2.9/pdftex/config/pdftex.map}]
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
                }
l.32 \end {align}

?
```

the piece of text is was referring to is:

```
\begin{align}
$V_x$ en $V_y$  &, dit zijn de snelheden in x- en y-richting. Hier is het assenstelsel bevestigd aan de horizon.\\
$C_L$ en $C_D$  &, dit zijn respectievelijk de lift- en drag coëfficiënten die op te zoeken zijn voor  NACA-vleugels, deze worden gebruikt de dynamische druk ($\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2$) om de lift en de drag te berekenen. Deze zijn afhankelijk van de vleugelvorm en de invalshoek van de stroming.\\
$C_{D,0}$ &, de coëfficiënt die samen met de dynamische druk aangeeft wat de drag is bij een situatie zonder lift; met andere woorden, als de angle of attack $0^0$ bedraagt.\\
e &, ellipsfactor. Dit getal tussen 0 en 1 geeft aan in hoeverre de vleugelvorm overeenkomt met een ellipsvorm.\\
\onimus  &, dit is de hoek tussen de richting van de snelheid van de glider en de x-as. Deze hoek bestaat uit de hoek tussen glider en de horizon, \beta, opgeteld bij de instroomhoek of ‘angle of attack’ \alpha.\\
AR &, de aspectratio. Dit is de verhouding die aangeeft hoe slank de vleugels zijn gedimensioneerd. Dit getal is dimensieloos en wordt gegeven door de relatie $AR= \frac{b^2}{A_{wing}}$
\end{align}
```

Comment: You should not have any of that text insde `align` what did you intend it to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for `tabular` (for text) not `align` (which is for displayed equations)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\newcommand\onimus{??}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}

\begin{tabular}{lp{8cm}}
$V_x$ en $V_y$  &, dit zijn de snelheden in x- en y-richting. Hier is het assenstelsel bevestigd aan de horizon.\\
$C_L$ en $C_D$  &, dit zijn respectievelijk de lift- en drag coëfficiënten die op te zoeken zijn voor  NACA-vleugels, deze worden gebruikt de dynamische druk ($\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2$) om de lift en de drag te berekenen. Deze zijn afhankelijk van de vleugelvorm en de invalshoek van de stroming.\\
$C_{D,0}$ &, de coëfficiënt die samen met de dynamische druk aangeeft wat de drag is bij een situatie zonder lift; met andere woorden, als de angle of attack $0^0$ bedraagt.\\
e &, ellipsfactor. Dit getal tussen 0 en 1 geeft aan in hoeverre de vleugelvorm overeenkomt met een ellipsvorm.\\
\onimus  &, dit is de hoek tussen de richting van de snelheid van de glider en de x-as. Deze hoek bestaat uit de hoek tussen glider en de horizon, 
$\beta$%math!
, opgeteld bij de instroomhoek of ‘angle of attack’ 
$\alpha$%math
.\\
AR &, de aspectratio. Dit is de verhouding die aangeeft hoe slank de vleugels zijn gedimensioneerd. Dit getal is dimensieloos en wordt gegeven door de relatie $AR= \frac{b^2}{A_{wing}}$
\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: probably the `,` should be at the end of the first column not the start of the second.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to set this is to use `itemize`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}[leftmargin=1cm,labelsep=0.5cm]
    \item[$V_x$, $V_y$,] dit zijn de snelheden in x- en y-richting. Hier is het assenstelsel bevestigd aan de horizon.
    \item[$C_L$, $C_D$,] dit zijn respectievelijk de lift- en drag coëfficiënten die op te zoeken zijn voor  NACA-vleugels, deze worden gebruikt de dynamische druk ($\frac{1}{2}\rho v^2$) om de lift en de drag te berekenen. Deze zijn afhankelijk van de vleugelvorm en de invalshoek van de stroming.
    \item[$C_{D,0}$,] de coëfficiënt die samen met de dynamische druk aangeeft wat de drag is bij een situatie zonder lift; met andere woorden, als de angle of attack $0^\circ$ bedraagt.
    \item[$e$,] ellipsfactor. Dit getal tussen 0 en 1 geeft aan in hoeverre de vleugelvorm overeenkomt met een ellipsvorm.
    \item[$\ominus$,] dit is de hoek tussen de richting van de snelheid van de glider en de $x$-as. Deze hoek bestaat uit de hoek tussen glider en de horizon, $\beta$, opgeteld bij de instroomhoek of ‘angle of attack’ $\alpha$.
    \item[$AR$,] de aspectratio. Dit is de verhouding die aangeeft hoe slank de vleugels zijn gedimensioneerd. Dit getal is dimensieloos en wordt gegeven door de relatie $AR=\frac{b^2}{A_{\mathrm{wing}}}$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Also:

- You have a typo for one of the symbols. I think it should be `\ominus` instead of `\onimus`.
- You don't want to use `0^0` to type zero degrees. Instead use `0^\circ` or have a look at the [gensymb package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/84471/103046).
- You probably want to type `A_{\mathrm{wing}}` in the last line, to have 'wing' in normal textmode letters.