# Degree symbol in bib file

Tags: biblatex, symbols

I can't get a the degree symbol to appear in the title.

I have tried:

```
title={Surface Tension of Alcohol and Water from 20 to 50{\degree}},
```

and

```
title={Surface Tension of Alcohol and Water from 20 to 50{$\degree$}},
```

And my Latex file is below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,firstinits=true,natbib=true,uniquename=false,uniquelist=false, maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}

\nocite{*}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

\end{document}
```

The error I get is:

> Undefined control sequence \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to define the `\degree` command first. See [Macro for degree symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22086/macro-for-degree-symbol) for possible pretty degree symbols.

A quick & dirty fix that works is just to change the `\degree` to `${}^\circ$`, so

```
    title={Surface Tension of Alcohol and Water from 20 to 50${}^\circ$},
```

Comment: Thanks, I was just confused because \degree already seemed to be defined according to TeXstudio

Answer (score 0):

Nine years after the question was asked... because modern LaTeX toolchains support UTF-8, you can include the degree symbol directly:

```
title={Surface Tension of Alcohol and Water from 20 to 50°},
```

If units were appropriate, then you should protect them from any possible conversion to lower case.  For example:

```
title = {Greenhouse-gas emission targets for limiting global warming to 2°{C}}
```

For more discussion of degree symbols, see [a similar question on the Zotero discussion forums](https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/70966/degree-celsius-symbol-c-in-bibtex-title-help).

For more discussion of capitalization see [BibTeX loses capitals when creating .bbl file](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10772/bibtex-loses-capitals-when-creating-bbl-file).